# Is there a Firebug / fancyBox conflict?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, firebug, fancybox-2

I use [fancyBox (v2.1.5)](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and work with Firefox version 35.0.1 and Firebug 2.0.7. When I open the Firebug window fancyBox is not working anymore. Are there any settings I could change to get it to work?

I have the problem also on the [official demo page](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/).

Comment: same versions and no problem or whatsoever, not even at the demo page. you may need to [refresh](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings) firefox

Comment: I found the problem. I also have the FireQuery Plug-In for Firebug which causes the problem. I deactivated it and everything was okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireQuery 1.4.1 is known to cause JavaScript execution problems in combination with current versions of Firefox and Firebug 2.0.*. This is also [mentioned in the Firebug FAQ](https://getfirebug.com/faq#Firebug_is_breaking_my_JavaScript._How_can_I_fix_that).

As FireQuery development is abandoned, you need to disable/remove it to get your page to work correctly.

Note that part of FireQuery's functionality is integrated within the [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel) Firebug 2.0.