# fancyBox not working in Firefox when debugger on

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug, fancybox-2

I am using jquery.fancybox.pack-2.1.5.js. When Firebug is open in Firefox, fancyBox stops working.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: is it working while your debugger off?

Comment: Yes, It is working when firebug is off.when I remove firequery, then it is working

Comment: This is issue with firbug. When Firequery is installed, there is a issue. But I need alternate solution for this.

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/faq#Firebug_is_breaking_my_JavaScript._How_can_I_fix_that

Comment: How to resolve this issue on coding level? User is not going to disable firequery.

Comment: Is it possible to throw a fiddle together that reproduces the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28256664/1055987

Comment: The solution is to disable FireQuery. There is no simple coding solution besides avoiding JavaScript libraries completely. Note that part of FireQuery's features is implemented within the [*Events* side panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Events_Side_Panel) in Firebug 2.0.